# Read a C# serialized class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have an application that writes to a serialized class, in a binary format. Opening the file in notepad shows some data and what appears to be the structure.

Is there any way of reading (and hopefully editing) this in a GUI debug view, such as in visual studio or with a third party application, without writing the code to parse/de-serialize it?

Or should I just go ahead and write a wrapper that will desterilize into an `object` and output that?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily deserialize the file using the [BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netframework-4.7) class.